# ElasticSearch matching no more than query terms

Tags: elasticsearch

For a search like "w1 w2 w3" I only want to retrieve documents that contain some of the query terms but no more. So documents containing "w1", "w2", "w3", "w1 w2", "w1 w3", "w2 w3" or "w1 w2 w3" would be ok, but not a document containing "w1 w2 w3 w4". I easily did it by programming but would like to do it with ElasticSearch => any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Use the query string query: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

```
{
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(w1 OR w2 OR w3 OR (w1 AND w2) OR (w1 AND w3) OR (w2 AND W3) 
                OR (w1 AND w2 AND w3))"
    }
}
```

OR

```
{
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(w1 OR w2 OR w3) AND NOT w4)"
    }
}
```

OR using the bool query: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

```
{
    "bool": {
        "should":   { "match": "w1 w2 w3" },
        "must_not": { "match": "w4" }
    }
}
```

keeping having fun with es;-)

Ok, after your comment i better understand what you want to do. You could use query string query with regular expressions:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_regular_expressions

```
{
  "query_string":{
    "query":"/(w1|w2|w3|)(w1|w2|w3|)(w1|w2|w3)(w1|w2|w3|)(w1|w2|w3|)/"
  }
}
```

This one would match w1,w1,w1,w1,w1 too, so you have to play a bit around with it. I hope the idea is enough that you can contintue. You have to create a regexp that matches your needs, my idea is only a short thought:-)

Comment: thanks for your help Gizzmo, but it does not work:
- option 1: returns results including w4
- options 2 and 3: in fact, w4 stands for "any other word that is not w1 nor w2 nor w3", so it belongs to a possibly infinite set of words, so it is not possible to make the hole list of words to be excluded (maybe i was not clear about this point, sorry)